# c++ ethereum could not open wallet

Tags: accounts, json-rpc, cpp-ethereum

Created 3 accounts as follows:

$ **eth account new**

```
Couldn't open wallet. Does it exist?
Enter a passphrase with which to secure this account:
Please confirm the passphrase by entering it again: 
Created key 0d3860d4-48b0-2a5e-9677-2e3407f41a48
  ICAP: XE173DQUQX2GT7YB1KPVK75A7RO17YCS2F
  Address: {00cde0300ff89aac1850e1d1c02929ba9bf70717}
```

$ **eth account new**

```
Couldn't open wallet. Does it exist?
Enter a passphrase with which to secure this account: person
Please confirm the passphrase by entering it again: person
Created key a50567a5-456e-2162-781b-e75fddc54a12
  ICAP: XE411X0X8K6BJ8AJ28HXU9Q0EX3J7GOPKH
  Address: {0074b96916bf30f7484ec6510923d33d13881371}
```

$ **eth account new**

```
Couldn't open wallet. Does it exist?
Enter a passphrase with which to secure this account: miner
Please confirm the passphrase by entering it again: miner
Created key 1e6674fd-bbf3-d7c3-b608-ec2d74260013
  ICAP: XE381P6BO9O6ZGEMM8XY0NXKSVHIYGWO8M
  Address: {006773224bca7cdfca7a487964a5861543bb7ab6}
```

Not sure why the message:

**Couldn't open wallet. Does it exist?**

Then start a private blockchain peer:

$ `eth -j --no-ipc --json-rpc-port 8081 -a '006773224bca7cdfca7a487964a5861543bb7ab6' --client-name 'test' --listen-ip 127.0.0.1 --listen 30001 --network-id 12321 --no-discovery`

Try to list the accounts using the following command:

`curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_accounts","params":[],"id":1}' htt://127.0.0.1:8081`

Get back the following response:

> {"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":["0x00a81525276c4e9e1b517e2fff7f7e2a979c3bbb"]}

Was expecting to see my 3 accounts. Any help appreciated.